# What does this absolute value notation mean?

Tags: linear-regression

In a regression model function, What does this absolute value notation mean?

[image]

Comment: For $n$-dimensional vectors $||\cdot||_2$ typically represents the Euclidean, or standard, norm.  $||v||_2 = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+...+v_n^2}.$

Comment: $||x||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}}$

Comment: Even more generally, $\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$ is the [$p$-norm for $\ell_p$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) which Euclidean norm/space is an example of.  In your specific example, the super-script $2$ is there as a power so $\|x\|_2^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2$

Comment: @D.B. considering x is also a matrix, what would $ x^{(n)} $ mean

Comment: I actually think that $x^{(n)}$ and $y^{(n)}$ are just vectors.  The quantity you have shown looks like a measure of the error between your data $y^{(n)}$ and your regression model.